# Can not configure systemd inside a chrooted environment?

Tags: systemd, apt, upgrade, chroot

After chrooting inside a folder and some other tweaks I finally updated the packages with:

```
apt update
```

But it is showing:

```
    Setting up systemd (245.5-3) ...
    Detected unsafe path transition /var/log → /var/log/journal during 
    canonicalization of /var/log/journal.
    Detected unsafe path transition /var/log → /var/log/journal during 
    canonicalization of /var/log/journal.
    Detected unsafe path transition /var/log → /var/log/journal during canonicalization of /var/log/journal.
    dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
     installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 73
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-systemd:armhf:
    libpam-systemd:armhf depends on systemd (= 245.5-3); however:
    Package systemd is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:armhf (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Errors were encountered while processing:
    systemd
 libpam-systemd:armhf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What am I supposed to do to fix this problem? I am using Raspbian as the host OS.

Answer (score 2):

Logs say there are unsafe path transitions. This happens because the target dir is user-owned. You should chroot into a `root`-owned directory.